# Find duplicates in a field then update another field with a Y or N with Python (ArcGIS)

Tags: python, python-2.7, arcgis

I am attempting to create a python script that will identify duplicated records within a points shapefile with a Y or N (possibility of over 5000 records). Similar to this:

xyCombine   |      dplicate

E836814.148873 N814378.125749   |

E836814.148873 N814378.125749   |

E836815.033548 N814377.614688   |

E836815.033548 N814377.614688   |

E836815.033548 N814377.614688   |

E836818.016542 N814371.411850   |

I wish to process the field xyCombine for duplicates and update another field (dplicate) with a Y or N if it's a duplicate or not. With the desired outcome as:

xyCombine   |      dplicate

E836814.148873 N814378.125749   |   Y

E836814.148873 N814378.125749   |   Y

E836815.033548 N814377.614688   |   Y

E836815.033548 N814377.614688   |   Y

E836815.033548 N814377.614688   |   Y

E836818.016542 N814371.411850   |   N

Below is my attempt:

```
# Process: Searches xyCombine field for any duplicates
duplicateCount = 0
inShapefile = pointsShapefile
fieldName = "xyCombine"
shpFRows = arcpy.UpdateCursor(inShapefile)
shpFRow = shpFRows.next()
fieldList = []
while shpFRow:
    if shpFRow.isNull(fieldName) == False and len(str(shpFRow.getValue(fieldName)).strip()) > 1:
            fieldList.append(shpFRow.getValue(fieldName))
    shpFRow = shpFRows.next()
duplicateList = [x for x, y in collections.Counter(fieldList).items() if y > 1]
print duplicateList
selectFile = pointsShapefile
selectFields = ('xyCombine','dupCHK')
shpFRows = arcpy.UpdateCursor(selectFile,selectFields)
shpFRow1 = shpFRows.next()
while shpFRow1:
    if shpFRow1.isNull(fieldName) == False and len(str(shpFRow1.getValue(fieldName)).strip()) > 1:
        for row in duplicateList:
            if shpFRow1.getValue(fieldName) == row:
                duplicate += 1
                row[1] = "Y"
            else:
                row[1] = "N"
            cursor.updateRow(row)
        shpFRow1 = shpFRows.next()
if duplicateCount > 0:
    print ""
    print "*** "+str(duplicate)+" duplicated points. ***"
    print ""
```

If I do not include

```
    row[1] = "Y"
else:
    row[1] = "N"
cursor.updateRow(row)
```

The script executes properly printing the total amount of duplicates, however does not update the field duplicates with either Y or N values which is important as it will provide a csv error report later down the script.

However when I do include it, I get the following error message:

Python 2.7.2 (default, Jun 12 2011, 15:08:59) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32

[u'E836814.148873 N814378.125749', u'E836815.033548 N814377.614688', u'E836818.016542 N814371.41185']

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ Duplicate Points Check\Python Scripts\DuplicatePointsCheck_TEST1.py", line 458, in 
    DuplicatePointsCheck()
  File "C:\ Duplicate Points Check\Python Scripts\DuplicatePointsCheck_TEST1.py", line 94, in DuplicatePointsCheck
    row[1] = "N"
TypeError: 'unicode' object does not support item assignment>>>

I understand that there are tools within ArcGIS that will provide possible solutions through field calculator. However I want to strengthen my understanding of Python as I am quite new to Python. I apologise if this question has been posed before, but I have trawled the internet and the only results of my search included locating and removing duplicated records. If any of you guys could steer me in the right direction, it would be of great help. Thank you in advance.

Comment: The records in your example file are sorted. Are the records in your real file sorted as well?

Comment: @gboffi: Nah, the records in the real file aren't sorted. I was just trying to set clarify my issue.

Comment: Cross-posted at http://gis.stackexchange.com/q/129860/115

Answer (score 0):

There's not enough information to be sure, but it appears that you're using ArcGIS 10.1 or newer. If that's the case, it looks like you're trying to use the new Data Access version of UpdateCursor but are actually calling the pre<10.0 version of UpdateCursor.

I haven't used ArCGIS 10.0 recently, but from the documentation it appears the syntax has changed. The ArcGIS documentation [lists this method](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/03q3/03q30000008n000000.htm) for assigning values to fields using an UpdateCursor:

```
for row in cursor:
    # field2 will be equal to field1 multiplied by 3.0
    row.setValue(field2, row.getValue(field1) * 3.0)
    cursor.updateRow(row)
```

You appear to be using the Data Access syntax, which is as follows, again [from the ArcGIS 10.2 documentation](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/UpdateCursor/018w00000014000000/):

```
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(fc, fields) as cursor:
# Update the field used in Buffer so the distance is based on road 
# type. Road type is either 1, 2, 3 or 4. Distance is in meters. 
for row in cursor:
    # Update the BUFFER_DISTANCE field to be 100 times the 
    # ROAD_TYPE field.
    row[1] = row[0] * 100
    cursor.updateRow(row)
```

Make sure you're using arcpy.da.UpdateCursor to create your cursor; I expect that will solve your problem.

Comment: I am using ArcGIS 10.1. Also, I substituted arcpy.UpdateCursor with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor and had the following error message:


if shpFRow.isNull(fieldName) == False and len(str(shpFRow.getValue(fieldName)).strip()) > 1:
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'isNull'

Comment: Again, I'm not 100% certain, but it appears that the row object returned by the old `arcpy.UpdateCursor` function is distinct from what is returned by `arcpy.da.UpdateCursor`. [Per the documentation](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//018w00000014000000), the `next` method: "Returns the next row as a tuple. The order of fields will be returned in the order they were specified when creating the cursor." Therefore, the isNull method doesn't work on the row. You'll have to reference the value as `shpFRow[0]`. You'll also need to use some other way to test for nullity.